# I want to get R code multifacet bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

Hi I want to make the multi facet bar chart.

The independent variable is one and dependent variables are 4. The dependent variables don't share the same y-axis values. some variable values are 0-10 and few are 100-1000. so I want multiple facet

I tried different codes but did not work

my results are one facet because the code I am following is multifacet in one variables whereas I have multiple variables and one x-axis variable

Answer (score 0):

If you say you have 4 dependent variables I'm guessing you have 1 column for each one. You could use `gather()`function from the `tidyr` package to make your data "longer", then add a `facet_wrap()` to your `ggplot`code.